# iOS - Amazon S3 Slow Download

Tags: iphone, ios, amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, amazon-cloudfront

I am creating an iOS app that allows users to write lets say a status update and people can comment on it, like it, interact with it in multiple ways, basically the status update has multiple properties that would be stored with it. Imagine an app with a home-screen of more than 50 of these status updates represented into a table view.

Now take your eyes away and focus on a practice/demo app, a developer trying to master the techniques before the big game (thats me!) So essentially, I have started out by setting up an S3 bucket based in Singapore. I live in Singapore, so there is a server nearby and really everything should be fast and smooth. Except, its just not. Its slow, and its starting to make me annoyed.

I know an app that uses S3 that loads high-definition panorama images with comments, likes etc. and it takes a second or a bit more for all this data to load. I am not sure how they actually carry out the process, I know they store the images on S3 but thats all I know. In my starter demo, I simply upload some pieces of text (say 20) then download them and it takes like 15 seconds under my 60 mbps wifi! These pieces of text don't even exceed a sentence each, they are phrases, so I am really kind of confused here.

I have CloudFront setup but isn't it for websites? I have the manage distributions and URL things all setup but how to setup in my code? This is probably my biggest question to nail down for release later in my other app. Even so, I live in Singapore and the bucket is in the Singapore server, so CloudFront for self-testing / practicing wouldn't be mandatory.

I find this extremely confusing, here is some annotated code I have produced, any problems, misconceptions that is leading it to be slow?

```
- (void)loadObjects {

S3ListObjectsRequest  *listObjectRequest = [[S3ListObjectsRequest alloc] initWithName: @"testbucketquotes.rohanprostudios"];
S3ListObjectsResponse *listObjectResponse = [[AmazonClientManager s3] listObjects:listObjectRequest];
if(listObjectResponse.error != nil)
{
}
else
{
    S3ListObjectsResult *listObjectsResults = listObjectResponse.listObjectsResult;

    if (objects == nil) {
        objects = [[NSMutableArray alloc] initWithCapacity:[listObjectsResults.objectSummaries count]];
    }
    else {
        [objects removeAllObjects];
    }

    // By defrault, listObjects will only return 1000 keys
    // This code will fetch all objects in bucket.
    NSString *lastKey = @"";
    for (S3ObjectSummary *objectSummary in listObjectsResults.objectSummaries) {

        if ([[objectSummary key] rangeOfString: @"UploadedQuote"].location != NSNotFound) {

        [objects addObject:[objectSummary key]];
        lastKey = [objectSummary key];

        }
    }

    while (listObjectsResults.isTruncated) {
        listObjectRequest = [[S3ListObjectsRequest alloc] initWithName: @"testbucketquotes.rohanprostudios"];
        listObjectRequest.marker = lastKey;

        listObjectResponse = [[AmazonClientManager s3] listObjects:listObjectRequest];
        if(listObjectResponse.error != nil)
        {                
            break;
        }

        listObjectsResults = listObjectResponse.listObjectsResult;

        for (S3ObjectSummary *objectSummary in listObjectsResults.objectSummaries) {

            if ([[objectSummary key] rangeOfString: @"UploadedQuote"].location != NSNotFound) {

                [objects addObject:[objectSummary key]];

            }

            lastKey = [objectSummary key];
        }
    }

    if (objects.count) {

        for (int i = 0; i <= objects.count - 1; i++) {

            S3GetObjectRequest *req = [[S3GetObjectRequest alloc] initWithKey:[objects objectAtIndex: i] withBucket: @"testbucketquotes.rohanprostudios"];

            `// asynchronously loads text (adds to operation queue)`
            AsyncQuoteDownloader *quote = [[AsyncQuoteDownloader alloc] initWithRequest:req andViewController: self];

            [operationQueue addOperation: quote]; 
            // in 'AsyncQuoteDownloader' when finished calls a method in this view controller adding the response to an array and reloading a table
        }

    }
  }

});
 }
```

Anything wrong with my code that is making it lag so much? I would have thought this would take a matter of milliseconds if an imaging service would take 1 second to load HQ images with likes and comments etc takes 1-2 seconds.

Thank you for any help...

Update

---

Ok, so the iteration of keys doesn't seem to be the problem here but rather the downloading of the objects. Any thoughts? Thanks...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is the first time I've ever even seen Objective C, so I may be completely wrong here. But... it looks like you're iterating through the keys of the entire bucket.  This is going to be really, really slow with any appreciable quantity of keys.

A better design would be store a lookup table in something like DynamoDB (since you're already using AWS).  You'd query there, get an array of matching id's (S3 keys), and then fetch the match objects from S3.

Comment: what is DynamoDB? Something I havent heard of, I'll check it out, but what do you mean by getting an array of matching id's and fetching the match. Just confused about this terminology...

Comment: Hi, I have updated  my question with what I think you may be talking about

Comment: DynamoDB is Amazon's version of a key-value store that runs on SSD-backed storage (it's a very fast NoSQL database).  Your code snippet above is just listing the table--it's obviously going to be empty until you add your data.  I'd recommend that you spend some time reading the AWS docs.  They're very well-written and will be able to provide you with more in-depth help than SO posters.

Comment: How can I make all the objects from my S3 bucket automatically add to DynamoDB so whenever a user uploads to S3 it adds to DynamoDB? Is there a DynamoDB console? So you are asking me to add all the keys to DynamoDB, get them and match them than get those objects with that key in S3? While that would be quicker with MANY keys in a bucket (this will be helpful with my later release app), in my example demo that wouldn't make a difference because I have 20 keys in my demo. This is not the slow part in my demo, the slow part is the download of the objects rather the download and iteration of keys.

Comment: Ah, yeah with just 20 keys, you'd be fine.  I'm not really sure what to recommend.  You could try testing the downloads to your computer using `curl` or `wget`.  If it's slow there, then the problem is with your network.  If it's fast, then the problem likely lays in the application code or library.

Comment: I can confirm its not my network. But anyways, how can I make all the objects from my S3 bucket automatically add to DynamoDB so whenever a user uploads to S3 it adds to DynamoDB? Is there a DynamoDB console? I might as well set this up so I can in my other release app where there will be many keys.

Comment: There's a DynamoDB console as part of the AWS Management Console.  That will let you set it up.  But to write to or read from the table, you'd need to write that into your application using the client library.

Comment: Thanks, I have looked through the classes/files and adapted to using DynamoDB, putting and getting items (keys) in specific tables then matching with correct key. Its not noticeably faster with 20 keys, but will be later on. Still however wondering where the problem may lie

Comment: DynamoDB has seriously made everything much faster, even with me fixing the region of my bucket which I accidentally set to US and thought it was to Singapore. So tick

Comment: Hi Jamieb, I have a question now, I ditched DynamoDB to use SimpleDB because it is geographically distributed and I dont have to download all keys and then match them, I can just use a select expression with SimpleDB (Its like SQL) and retrieve the keys that have attributes that match the expression. Is this the better option? Will it be just as fast? Considering I have many keys and DynamoDB has a single-download limit of 1 MB?

Answer (score 1):

Another option, as I used in my own iOS app, is to use Heroku as the app layer and create a POSTGRESQL record that points to your content. This way you can create rich queries in rails and mediate upload and download with the power of Rails, rather then paying for both DynamoDB and S3.

Comment: Thanks, however I have absolutely no clue what you are talking about! Sorry... what is Heroku? What is POSTGRESQL, and what is Rails? I am very much in my S3 shell so I am really a foreigner to these terms/services. Could you point me to any resources/examples to get me started and understanding? Thanks

Comment: I think this will explain everything:https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/ios-core-data-buildpack-app

Comment: Thanks Ill check that out, Id rather use S3 and DynamoDB however because Amazon has SES email service and SNS notification service so the whole thing seems very unified. BUt ill check this out and get back to you

Answer (score 0):

Turns out my bucket was set to US region and not Singapore region... #doh

Its faster now, its working fine

I just needed to set the `AmazonS3Client`'s endpoint to Singapore (SEA) region